# How do I get all colliders in a list to ignore each other?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This doesn't seem to be working. Should this work? I put it in Start. Thanks in advance.

```
    foreach (Collider nativeCollider in allColliders)
        foreach (Collider collider in allColliders)
            Physics.IgnoreCollision(nativeCollider, collider);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Would it work

Probably yes! But aren't you doing a lot of redundant work here?

```
Physics.IgnoreCollision(a, b);
```

equals doing

```
Physics.IgnoreCollision(b, a);
```

.. also not sure actually how Unity would treat

```
Physics.IgnoreCollision(a, a);
```

which you are also including ;)

What you rather want is excluding the pairs you already handled e.g. like this

```
for(var a = 0; a < allColliders.Count; a++)
{
    // Only iterate through the colliders behind the current one in the list
    // -> Makes no sense to ignore yourself
    // -> And the ones before have already been handled by the outer iterations before
    for(var b = a + 1; b < allColliders.Count; b++)
    {
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(allColliders[a], allColliders[b]);
    }
}
```

---

Way easier and more convenient though would be to simply put them all on a certain [Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) and then in the [Physics Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html) under [Layer Collision Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) make sure that this certain Layer does not collide with itself.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This is very helpful. I don't know enough about coding to create a solution this efficient. Thanks a bunch.